# How to use a 'checkbox' to update present address to same as permanent address in react js

Tags: reactjs, select

When set present address select box then id value show in permanent address select box.

Comment: Hello, in order to understand your problem, we need to see some code and more explanation. Please provide some code and describe your problem with more detail.

Comment: *visible confusion*

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you've asked for, from next time please give a clear description.Please excuse me for the css(Didn't use any), few bad react practises.I did it for state and country in the same way you can do it for city as well.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const country = {
  India: ["Telangana", "Punjab", "Delhi"],
  US: ["Florida", "Texas", "California"]
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {};
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      statecurVal: [],
      statepermVal: [],
      curCon: null,
      curStat: null,
      permCon: null,
      permStat: null
    };
  }
  renderCountries = () => {
    let opts = [];
    for (let i in country) {
      opts.push(<option value={i}>{i}</option>);
    }
    return opts;
  };
  changeState = e => {
    let con_sel = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ curCon: con_sel, statecurVal: country[con_sel] });
  };
  changeState2 = e => {
    let con_sel = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ permCon: con_sel, statepermVal: country[con_sel] });
  };
  copytopermAddr = e => {
    let val = e.target.checked;
    if (val) {
      this.setState({
        permCon: this.state.curCon,
        permStat: this.state.curStat,
        statepermVal: this.state.statecurVal
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Current Addr:</h1>
          <div>
            <select value={this.state.curCon} onChange={this.changeState}>
              {this.renderCountries()}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <select
              value={this.state.curStat}
              onChange={e => {
                let sta_sel = e.target.value;
                this.setState({ curStat: sta_sel });
              }}
            >
              {this.state.statecurVal.map(e => {
                return <option value={e}>{e}</option>;
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Same as Current</label>
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.copytopermAddr} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Permanent Addr:</h1>
          <div>
            <select value={this.state.permCon} onChange={this.changeState2}>
              {this.renderCountries()}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <select
              value={this.state.permStat}
              onChange={e => {
                let sta_sel = e.target.value;
                this.setState({ permStat: sta_sel });
              }}
            >
              {this.state.statepermVal.map(e => {
                return <option value={e}>{e}</option>;
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have three select box country state and city where onchange country change the state value. when select state in present address and click same as checbox value then permanent address state value is shown id of present address state.

Comment: @Princekumar You are not clear, correct me if I am wrong, you have three select box under temporary address and after selecting these 3 and when user clicks on same as temporary you want it to be copied to three select boxes of permanent address as well right?